# ls show in megabytes can be set in bash script ?

Tags: linux, bash, ls

To check the size in megabytes I have always to do --block-size=Mb. Can I set in bashrc so that when I do ls it should alway publish size in Mb?

Comment: `ls -lh` will show all sizes `h` indicates human readable format.

Answer (score 11):

This is an old question, but I found a solution [here](http://iosdevelopertips.com/bash/bash-trick-file-sizes-byte-kilobyte-megabyte-gigabyte.html) which is probably better and that I love:

```
ls -ahl
```

The `h` is for human-readable format, it uses Kb, Mb or Gb automatically.

Comment: The issue at hand is how to get it to always show the size in Mb.

Comment: @Max Smith How can we specify which is gonna be used from KB,MB or GB ? (Also, upvoted for the explanation of what 'h' does)

Comment: @Sandun It will pick whichever one is most appropriate. Something like 4.0 or 5.0K or 6.0M or 7.0G. The first one has no K/M/G because it's just bytes. Try it out yourself!

Comment: @MaxSmith Thanks, but I am wondering if there's a way the user can determine what's the appropriate unit of measurement is when getting the output?

Answer (score 9):

Add the following line to your `.bashrc` file

```
alias ls="ls --block-size=M"
```

Then logout and log back in. `ls` should now have the desired flags.

You could find this information using `man ls`:

> ```
> --block-size=SIZE
>               scale sizes by SIZE  before  printing  them;  e.g.,
>               '--block-size=M' prints sizes in units of 1,048,576
>               bytes; see SIZE format below
> ```

Comment: Why do you want logout and log back in? Just refreshing the .bashrc file is enough I guess? or opening a new terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Alias it:

```
alias ls="ls --block-size=Mb"
```

But do you really want to *always* see file sizes in MB?

Answer (score 1):

GNU `ls`, `df` and `du` from the GNU coreutils package will use the `BLOCK_SIZE` environment variable, if it exists in the current environment.

You may use this to get the effect that you want by setting and exporting `BLOCK_SIZE` in your shell's startup files (e.g. `~/.bashrc` or equivalent for interactive shells).

```
export BLOCK_SIZE=M    # or MiB (2^20 bytes), or MB (10^6 bytes)
```

If you only want to change the bock size used by `ls` (and not by `du` and `df`), then set `LS_BLOCK_SIZE` rather than `BLOCK_SIZE` (there is also `DU_BLOCK_SIZE` and `DF_BLOCK_SIZE`).

The block size set by the environment variable can still be overridden on the command line with `--block-size=somevalue`.

See also:

- [The coreutils documentation on "Block size"](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Block-size.html)